# Induced orientation on underlying real vector bundle of a complex bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

I am reading Milnor's "Characterstic classes". I am currently working through the chapter on Chern classes. In particular, he shows that any complex vector bundle induces a canonical orientation on it's underlying real vector bundle. At the end of the proof of this statement (which is on the first page of the chapter) he states

> "Now, if $\omega$ is a complex vector bundle, then applying this construction to every fiber of $\omega$, we obtain the required orientation for $\omega_{R}$."

Where $\omega_{R}$ is the underlying real vector bundle.

**I am having a hard time understanding why, by orienting the fibers of the underlying real vector space in this way (I review the construction below), one will always be able to orient the fibers in a "continuous" way across the whole manifold, thereby providing an orientation of the entire bundle.**

Obviously it can be done on any given elementary neighborhood, but I worry that the manifold may be too twisted and this construction will eventually run into a contradiction. If someone could help me to understand why this construction can always be done consistently I would appreciate that greatly.

As a reminder, the construction is as follows:

Given a complex vector space of dimension $n$, we choose a complex basis $\{a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\}$ and define the orientation of the underlying real vector space using the ordered $2n$-tuple $\{a_{1},i a_{1},\ldots,a_{n},i a_{n}\}$ as our basis. This is well defined since every complex basis for the space can be continuously connected by a path in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ (since this group is connected) and a continuous transformation cannot change orientation.

Comment: The orientation on the real vector space is independent of the basis of the complex vector space you choose. Thus happily do that in any coordinate chart, and the orientations you get on the real spaces automatically fit.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand why they have to match up everywhere. I don't see why we can't have a situation where two charts intersect in such a way as to make the induced orientations incompatible, like perhaps on something like a mobius strip where the orientation has to flip at some point. Perhaps I should take that as proof that the mobius strip cannot be given a complex structure? Is it is local triviality condition on a complex bundle that guarantees this consistency?

Comment: The coordinate change between two overlapping charts gives you a section in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. If you make that complex matrix $A$ real by identifying $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with the basis $e_1,\, i\cdot e_1,\, e_2,\, i\cdot e_2,\, \ldots,\, e_n,\, i\cdot e_n$, you get a matrix $A_\mathbb{R}$ with positive determinant ($\det A_\mathbb{R} = \lvert \det A\rvert^2$), so the coordinate change of the real bundle is orientation-preserving.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So it is the complex-linearity requirement on the local triviality of the bundle that provides this consistent orientation. Thank you.